# C# TreeView append all possible sequential nodes as string

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'm having difficulties with appending text from TreeView nodes as shown in the picture.

[TreeView example structure](http://s21.postimg.org/x2jxiboaf/tree_view_append.png)

I'm trying to achieve getting all possible ways of parent node and it's child nodes appended as follow:

- a -> b -> c -> d
- a -> b -> c -> e
- a -> b -> f

I have this C# code written but it's not working properly as I want and I'm kinda stuck on this problem, so that's why I'm asking for your help.

```
private static List<Node> GetChildNodes(Node node, List<Node> parentNodes)
{
    List<Node> nodesNodes = new List<Node>();
    nodesNodes.Add(node);

    if(node.ChildNodes.Any())
    {
        foreach (var childnode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            nodesNodes.AddRange(GetChildNodes(childnode, parentNodes));
        }
    }

    return nodesNodes;
}

List<Node> appendedNodes = new List<Node>();
foreach(var node in parentNodes)  // all my parent nodes from db (those with parentId = null)
{
   var nodes = GetChildNodes(node, parentNodes);

   string fullNode = String.Join(", ", nodes .OrderByDescending(n => n.ParentId).Select(n => n.Name));

   appendedNodes.Add(new Node() { Id = nodes.OrderByDescending(l => l.ParentId).First().Id, Name = fullNode, ParentId = node.ParentId);
}
```

Then I consume **appendedNodes** in the UI by showing the property **Name** (which is in the form of a -> b -> c....)

But this returns me this result according to the picture: a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f

Can you give me a heads up with the solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a string representation of all paths in your tree you can very well use `TreeNode.FullPath`. If you want paths as node collections you can use `TreeNode.Tag` and instead of adding to strings accumulate into a collection stored in the tag of the node.
[image: running app]

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTagPaths (TreeView tv) { return GetTagPaths(tv.Nodes[0]); }
public IEnumerable<string> GetFullPaths (TreeView tv){ return GetFullPaths(tv.Nodes[0]); }
public IEnumerable<string> GetTagPaths (TreeNode node)
{
  if (node.Tag == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Tag as string))
    node.Tag = node.Text;
  foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
  {
    child.Tag = (node.Tag as string) + "->" + child.Text;
    if (child.IsLeaf())
      yield return (child.Tag as string);
    else
      foreach (string childPath in GetTagPaths(child))
        yield return childPath;
  }      
}
public IEnumerable<string> GetFullPaths (TreeNode node)
{
  if (node.IsLeaf())
      yield return node.FullPath;
  else
    foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
    {
      foreach (string childPath in GetFullPaths(child))
        yield return childPath;  
    }      
}
```

and this extension method

```
public static bool IsLeaf (this System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode tn)
{
  System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection children = tn.Nodes;
  return (children == null || children.Count == 0);
}
```